# Unbound record field api_key in my OCaml code

Tags: ocaml

I keep getting the below error when I run `dune build`:

```
File "lib/ip2locationio.ml", line 25, characters 73-80:
25 |     let uri = Uri.of_string ("https://api.ip2location.io/?key=" ^ config.api_key ^ "&format=" ^ config.format ^ "&source=" ^ config.source ^ "&source_version=" ^ config.source_version ^ "&ip=" ^ ip ^ lang_str) in
                                                                              ^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound record field api_key
```

I have looked through the other posts with similar issues and I've provided the signature in the .mli file but still unable to fix the issue.

My ip2locationio.ml file

```
open Lwt
open Cohttp
open Cohttp_lwt_unix
open Yojson

module Configuration = struct
  type config = {
    source_version : string;
    api_key : string;
    format: string;
    source: string
  }
  
  let init api_key = {
    source_version = "1.0.0";
    api_key = api_key;
    format = "json";
    source = "sdk-ocaml-iplio"
  }
end

module Ip_geolocation = struct
  let call_api config ip lang =
    let lang_str = if lang == "" then "" else "&lang=" ^ lang in
    let uri = Uri.of_string ("https://api.ip2location.io/?key=" ^ config.api_key ^ "&format=" ^ config.format ^ "&source=" ^ config.source ^ "&source_version=" ^ config.source_version ^ "&ip=" ^ ip ^ lang_str) in
    
    Lwt_main.run begin
      Client.get uri >>= fun (resp, body) ->
        let code = resp |> Response.status |> Code.code_of_status in
        let json_promise = body |> Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string in
        json_promise >>= (fun json_string ->
          return (code, json_string)
        )
    end
  
  (** Call the API to get geolocation info *)
  let lookup config ip lang =
    let code, json_string = call_api config ip lang in
    let json = Basic.from_string json_string in
    (code, json)
end
```

My ip2locationio.mli file

```
module Configuration :
  sig
    type config = {
      source_version : string;
      api_key : string;
      format: string;
      source: string;
    }
    val init : string -> config
  end
module Ip_geolocation :
  sig
    val lookup :
      Configuration.config -> string -> string -> int * Yojson.Basic.t
  end
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction. I am not sure what else I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider a simpler example that replicates your error.

```
# module A = struct
    type t = {x : int}
  end;;
module A : sig type t = { x : int; } end
# module B = struct
    let foo c = c.x
  end;;
Error: Unbound record field x
# module C = struct
    let foo (c : A.t) = c.x
  end;;
module C : sig val foo : A.t -> int end
```

Attempting to create a new `A.t` value runs into similar issues.

```
# A.{x = 5};;
- : A.t = {A.x = 5}
# {A.x = 7};;
- : A.t = {A.x = 7}
# {x = 4};;
Error: Unbound record field x
```

A straightforward resolution of this issue would be to explicitly type the function argument.

```
  let call_api (config : Configuration.config) ip lang =
```

As a sidenote, consider the following line from your code:

> ```
>     let lang_str = if lang == "" then "" else "&lang=" ^ lang in
> ```

`==` in OCaml checks for physical equality: *are these two values literally the same value?* However, `=` checks for structural equality: *are these two values equal?*

You likely wanted:

```
    let lang_str = if lang = "" then "" else "&lang=" ^ lang in
```

You may also find it advantageous for readability to use `Printf.sprintf` in place of numerous string concatenations.

```
"https://api.ip2location.io/?key=" ^ config.api_key ^ "&format=" ^ config.format ^ "&source=" ^ config.source ^ "&source_version=" ^ config.source_version ^ "&ip=" ^ ip ^ lang_str
```

Becomes:

```
Printf.sprintf 
  "https://api.ip2location.io/?key=%s&format=%s&source=%s&source_version=%s&ip=%s%s"
  config.api_key config.format config.source 
  config.source_version ip lang_str
```

Answer (score 1):

To add onto @Chris answer you can also do:

```ml
config.Configuration.api_key
```

To help OCaml infer the type. I'm not sure of all of the caveats that come from using this, but I know it works for your example.